# Overwrite a specific line in a text file with php

Tags: php, line, overwrite

Need to find a simple solution to the following:

I have a php file that, when executed, should be able to replace a specific line of code within itself, with a different value on that line.

I came up with this so far:

```
$file = "file.php";
$content = file($file); 
foreach($content as $lineNumber => &$lineContent) {
    if($lineNumber == 19) {

        $lineContent .= "replacement_string";
    }
}

$allContent = implode("", $content);
file_put_contents($file, $allContent);
```

However, that does not replace the specific line. It adds the new string on a new line and that's it. I need that specific line ERASED and then REPLACED with the new string, on that line.

How would I continue about doing that? I'd love some pointers.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Store your data in a database or even a text-file but don't modify the script you are executing. Or any other script.

Comment: This sounds line the foundation for a _huge_ security issue...

Comment: Also this approach won't scale. It will only work for reasonable small files. Because you keep the whole file in memory, actually 2 times at a time.

Comment: 19th line after `file()` usage? why not try change 18th index

Answer (score 2):

Since file() creates an array, make use of the index to select the line.
Don't forget that array indexes start at 0!

```
$file = "file.php";
$content = file($file); 

$content[19] = "replacement_string\r\n";

$allContent = implode("", $content);
file_put_contents($file, $allContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `.=` in the `$lineContent .= "replacement_string";` line. Just use `=` or use the [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function.